# Bug on using Graphics class API for two Movie clips

Tags: flash, flashdevelop, flash-cs6, actionscript-3

I have two Movie clips that are added to the stage via AS3 using Flash Develop, one movie clip named `playerHook` and the other `fisherman`. Both are added to the stage in my main constructor function like so:

```
fisherman = new mcFisherman;
stage.addChild(fisherman);
fisherman.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) + 250;
fisherman.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - 100;
```

I have a separate function called `playerHookLine();` which is called by my main event enter frame gameloop.

This function connects two movie clips with a line and is supposed to act like a fishing pole line. Which It does very nicely.

The problem I am having is when I start to play the game my hook line doesn't register the `HitTestObject` like my `playerHook` movie clip does.

I have managed to tweak the code a little bit and it does start to register but then none of the points where the line is supposed to be connected are correct, its all over the place. Here is the code for the function:

```
private function playerHookLine():void 
{
    graphics.clear();
    graphics.lineStyle(1, 0, 1);
    graphics.moveTo(fisherman.x, fisherman.y);
    graphics.curveTo(playerHook.x, playerHook.y, mouseX, mouseY);

}
```

When I change the code to this:

```
private function playerHookLine():void 
{
    playerHook.graphics.clear();
    playerHook.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0, 1);
    playerHook.graphics.moveTo(fisherman.x, fisherman.y);
    playerHook.graphics.curveTo(playerHook.x, playerHook.y, mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

then it registers the hitTest along with the hook but the line is no longer in the correct position. What am I doing wrong, how should I correctly use the Graphics API code? I want the line and the PlayerHook to both hitTest with the enemy on screen but I also want the line to still be connected to the fisherman and the playerHook.

Lastly, my playerHook is controlled by the mouse. So it moves wherever the mouse moves.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private function playerHookLine():void 
    {


        var playerHookGlobalPos:Point = playerHook.localToGlobal(new Point());
        var fishermanGlobalPos:Point = fisherman.localToGlobal(new Point());

        playerHook.graphics.clear();
        playerHook.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0, 1);
        playerHook.graphics.moveTo(fisherman.x, fisherman.y);
        playerHook.graphics.curveTo(playerHookGlobalPos.x, playerHookGlobalPos.y, mouseX, mouseY);


    }
```

but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of difference between,

`graphics.moveTo(fisherman.x, fisherman.y);` // refers to Main class i.e super. (Stage (Global) co-ordinates)

and

`playerHook.graphics.moveTo(fisherman.x, fisherman.y);` // This refers to playerHook object (Local co-ordinates).

Based on a info you gave, I think you have to use ,

[`globalToLocal()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal%28%29)

Comment: Oh okay. I didn't even think of trying that. Im pretty sure ill be using globalToLocal since my movie clip isnt nested correct? But when using this i would be using this method correct? playerHook.graphics.moveTo(fisherman.x, fisherman.y);

Comment: Alright ill try to figure it out. Ive done a lot of research on this subject and i have an idea of how to approach it. But its still giving me some problems. Ill post if i figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Where you want to place your line? I can help you?I have already done like this?

Comment: I want to place it on the stage connected to my fisherman.x and fisherman.y axis. From there I want to curve and have connected to the playerhook.x and the playerHook.y. I already accomplished this but the line doesnt register the hitTest with the playerHook as i stated above so thats why i need it to be playerHook.graphics.moveTo and etc... when its just graphics.moveTo, it doesnt register the hittest. Did i make sense?

Comment: I posted the code above in my question to show how im trying to do it right now. It register the hittest and doesnt get blocked behind other movieclips on the stage, but its not connected to the fisherman or the playerHook.